# Total function between two elements of sub_lists

Tags: list-manipulation

We have a list containing `IntegerDigits` elements as

```
list0={{0,0,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,1,0,1,0},
 {0,0,1,1,0,0},
 {0,0,1,1,1,0},
 {0,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,1,1,0,1,0},
 {0,1,1,1,1,0},
 {1,0,1,0,0,0},
  ...};
```

Two any arbitrary positions of each element can be definitely determined by `0` or `1`. For instants, in the above list, we have `0` in the first position and `1` in the fourth position. They are fixed and are not changeable. We have to create a list whose elements are `-1` or `+1`. If the `Total` between two mentioned positions is`Even` (if `evenQ=True`) it must be `+1`, otherwise it must be `-1`. Or we can say `(-1)^(Total[elements between first and fourth positions])`
I mean:

```
list1={{1}, (*0+0=0*)
       {-1}, (*0+1=1*)
       {-1}, (*1+0=1*)
       {+1},  (*1+1=2*)
       {+1},
       {-1},
       {+1},
       {+1},
       ....}
```

How can I do this aim?

Comment: Why do you write `(*0+0=0*)` for the first one? It has `1` in the 3rd position, and `0` in the 6th position.

Comment: Should the position be taken backwards because `IntegerDigits` puts the coefficient of the smallest power of the base at the end of the output list

Comment: Something like `(-1)^Total[list0[[All, {4, 5}]], {2}]`?

Comment: For your second comment you are right. So sorry. But for the first comment: there are two `0`s between `1` and `0`.

Comment: So sorry I corrected them.

Comment: @Coolwater, is right, I corrected them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list0 =
 {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
  {0,1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}};

If[#, 1, -1]& @* EvenQ @* Total /@ list0[[All, 4 ;; 5]]
```

> {1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1}

Or, similar to Carl Woll's comment,

```
(-1)^(Plus @@@ list0[[All, 4 ;; 5]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much but because the positions are arbitrary the `Total` maybe exceeds from 2 or 0

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you started out with the integers themselves:

```
ints = FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ list0
```

> {8, 10, 12, 14, 24, 26, 30, 40}

If that's the case, then you don't need `IntegerDigits`:

```
(-1)^Sign[Mod[BitAnd[2^1 + 2^2, #], 2^1 + 2^2]] & /@ ints 
(-1)^Sign[Mod[BitAnd[6, #], 6]] & /@ ints
```

> {1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1}

where `2^0` corresponds to the last element of `IntegerDigits` and `2^1` corresponds to the second last, etc.

Comment: What is dd? It was not defined!

Comment: @InzoBabaria I removed them

Comment: I cannot understand why `6`?!

Comment: I cannot generalize to an arbitrary case

Comment: @InzoBabaria If you meant the second and third position of some `IntegerDigit` output `{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}` it should be `2^4 + 2^3` i.e. the exponents must be how far from the last element of the `IntegerDigit` output you want to pick a digit

Comment: You might be interested in `BitGet[]`.

Comment: Your answer is very good and based on intelligent. But if possible, please let me accept @eldo's answer. Because I think it is more simple to me.